# Nested JSON to Pandas Dataframe in python

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to convert nested JSON data into a pandas dataframe. I know there is ample material on here about this but I still can't seem to get this working.
As you can see, I created a dataframe with the intent of grabbing only certain pieces of data (bedrooms, price, size, longitude, latitude).

Any help is appreciated.

Code below:

```
import json
import requests
import datetime
import pandas as pd
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
from urllib.request import urlopen
import json
import urllib.request, json 

end_page = 42

df = pd.DataFrame()#columns='Bedrooms','Price','Size','Longitude','Latitude')

for page in range(1,end_page+1):

    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.rentfaster.ca/api/search.json?proximity_type=location-city&novacancy=0&city_id=" + str(page)) as url:

        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())


        for x in data['listings']:
            for y in x['bedrooms'] and x['sq_feet']:
                print(y)
```

Answer (score 0):

The request that you are making has no attribute 'size'. The properties in the data are:

```
['address', 'address_hidden', 'availability', 'avdate', 'baths',
       'bedrooms', 'cats', 'city', 'community', 'den', 'dogs', 'email', 'id',
       'intro', 'latitude', 'link', 'location', 'longitude', 'marker', 'phone',
       'phone_2', 'preferred_contact', 'price', 'province', 'quadrant',
       'ref_id', 'rented', 'slide', 'sq_feet', 'status', 'thumb', 'thumb2',
       'title', 'type', 'userId', 'utilities_included', 'website']
```

Beyond that, the way I made it work is to create a temporary data frame, then drop all the columns that aren't in a named list. the code looks as follows:

```
    import json
    import requests
    import datetime
    import pandas as pd
    from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
    from urllib.request import urlopen
    import json
    import urllib.request, json

end_page = 42

columns_list = ['bedrooms','price','longitude','latitude']

df = pd.DataFrame(data=None, columns=columns_list)

for page in range(0,10):

    with urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.rentfaster.ca/api/search.json?proximity_type=location-city&novacancy=0&city_id=" + str(page)) as url:

        data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

        for entry in range(0, len(data['listings'])):
            df_temp = pd.DataFrame([data['listings'][entry]])
            df_temp = df_temp[columns_list]
            df = df.append(df_temp)
```

If you also wanted to collect the attribute 'size' then you would need to add 'sq_feet' to the list of columns you want to keep.

Note that the for loop only currently runs from 0-10 because after that it fails, I believe because a listing does not contain all the attributes that you are looking for. This can be fixed by sanitising the inputs.

Hope that helps!